# One with many in mysql, how to model?

Tags: mysql, sql

Each task can have many sub-tasks. Tasks can only be completed when all sub-tasks are

> task_id | parent_task_id | employee_id | completed

```
SELECT * from tasks WHERE task_id = x and parent_task_id = x
```

Now suppose I want to assign a single task to multiple employee (each employee can have multiple tasks at any time.)

What is the best way to model?

Comment: Employee Table--<- Employee Tasks Table >-- Task table..  this way a task, or a subtask could have one or many employees related.  EmployeeTasks has EmployeeID, taskID, Assigned Date, EstCompletionDT and CompletionDT and %complete and perhaps notes which an employee can update %complete and notes  to indicate progress.

Comment: Based on your question, I would also break out Tasks and SubTasks into their own tables. Create your main (parent) task in Tasks, and add sub tasks to SubTasks with a reference to Tasks.id. Then, in your logic you'd want to check to ensure all SubTasks are complete before users can complete/check off the main parent Task.

Comment: in normal form, Many-to-many relationships should be resolved with an junction/associative table.   I believe that's the case here.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
    TASKS
    id
    parent_id
    completed
    name

    EMPLOYEES
    id
    name

    EMPLOYEE_TASKS
    id
    employee_id
    task_id
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be a **weak entity** EMPLOYEE_TASKS. Meaning,
**1 to Many** from EMPLOYEE_TABLE to EMPLOYEE_TASKS
AND
**1 to Many** from TASKS_TABLE to EMPLOYEE_TASKS.
Now you can have Employee_id and Task_id to the EMPLOYEE_TASKS